# How to get ImageView ID from inflater in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using an inflater to show a popup setting menu made by me. It's composed by some images and buttons. After complete XML layout I'm started to code it, it opens correctly with this code:

```
    public void Settings_button(View view)
    {
        if (p != null)
            showPopup(Main_activity.this, p);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        int[] location = new int[2];
        ImageButton setting_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settings_button);

        // Get the x, y location and store it in the location[] array
        // location[0] = x, location[1] = y.
        setting_button.getLocationOnScreen(location);

        //Initialize the Point with x, and y positions
        p = new Point();
        p.x = location[0];
        p.y = location[1];
    }

    // The method that displays the popup.
    private void showPopup(final Activity context, Point p) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        int popupWidth = 500;
        int popupHeight = 300;

        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_popup_layout, viewGroup);

        // Creating the PopupWindow
        final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
        popup.setContentView(layout);
        popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
        popup.setHeight(popupHeight);
        popup.setFocusable(true);

        // Some offset to align the popup a bit to the right, and a bit down, relative to button's position.
        int OFFSET_X = 150;
        int OFFSET_Y = 30;

        // Displaying the popup at the specified location, + offsets.
        popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, p.x + OFFSET_X, p.y + OFFSET_Y);

    }
```

But now I need to get *ImageViews* IDs and *Buttons* IDs, I've used:

```
//In onCreate of Main_Activity
ImageView popup_setting_1_icon;
popup_setting_1_icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.setting_1_icon);
Button popup_setting_1_button;
popup_setting_1_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setting_1_button);
```

But when I'm starting to use this Views for example `popup_setting_1_icon.setImageResource(R.id.setting_done_icon);` I get application crash with `NullPointerException`.
I've read something like I should get pointers from inflater but I've tried to do so inside `showPopup` method but nothing. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: does your popup layout contains this image "popup_setting_1_icon"?

Comment: Show code where you are using `popup_setting_1_icon.setImageResource(R.id.setting_done_icon);` line

Comment: You declared `popup_setting_1_icon` as both a button and imageview, is one of those a typo? Or just showing what you tried? Regardless findViewById returns null if it can't find the id in the layout

Comment: @justDroid I've checked multiple times to see if it was a type error but nothing.

Comment: @cricket_007 It was a paste typo, I've corrected now

Comment: you have to initialize it in t his way:
ImageView popup_setting_1_icon;
popup_setting_1_icon = (ImageView)layout. findViewById(R.id.setting_1_icon);
Button popup_setting_1_button;
popup_setting_1_button = (Button)layout. findViewById(R.id.setting_1_button);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize views in show popup method:

```
ImageView popup_setting_1_icon;
popup_setting_1_icon = (ImageView)layout. findViewById(R.id.setting_1_icon);
Button popup_setting_1_button;
popup_setting_1_button = (Button)layout. findViewById(R.id.setting_1_button);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with programmatically inflating a container and populating it. This is what worked for me:

```
LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); 
LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById( 
    R.id.popup); 
View layout = inflator.inflate(R.layout.settings_popup_layout, null);
Button button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.setting_1_button);
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.setting_1_icon);
//bind data to view/buttons
viewGroup.addView(layout);
```

This is assuming your settings button and image views are inside the settings popup layout.

Comment: Forgot to add that on to the last line, should work now.

Comment: I think it might also be used in the inflate method in place of null